# Quotient by squares of finite rank

Tags: ring-theory, modules, p-adic-number-theory, quotient-spaces

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers.

> Why is $\mathcal{O}^\times/\mathcal{O}^{\times 2}$ of finite rank?

In particular, what do we get for $K=\mathbf{Q}$? And for $K=\mathbf{Q}_p$?

Comment: What is $\;K\;$ in the question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that $\Bbb Z^\times=\{\pm1\}$ so that the reason is very obvious in this case.

More generally, if $\cal O$ is the ring of integers in a number field $F$ a theorem of Dirichlet says that
$$
{\cal O}^\times\simeq T\times\Bbb Z^r
$$
where $T$ is a finite group (actually, the roots of $1$ in $F$) and $r=r_1+r_2-1$ where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings and $r_2$ the number of complex embedding of $F$.

Thus, the result is pretty clear because
$$
({\cal O}^\times)^2\simeq (T)^2\times2\Bbb Z^r.
$$

Comment: The theorem of Dirichlet was the step I missed then, thank you for the explanation !